# How are these pouches opened

Tags: sewing

I am trying to DIY a pouch similar to the one shown in the **first image** below.

**First Image**

[image]

However, I cannot figure out how the pouch can be opened once the ribbon bow is attached to it.

If the bow was tied as in the **second image**, we could untie the bow and open the pouch. But, since the bow in the first image is made and attached, I wonder how the pouch can be opened.

**Second Image**

[image]

Can anyone give an idea so as how the pouch in **first image** is made?

(All images above are rightfully owned by the respective creators. I am simply trying to create something similar for personal use.)

Comment: I'd very much like to see the backs of the pouches. I suspect the ornament on the ribbon is a brooch with a pin going through the entire pouch with a butterfly clasp or pin clasp on the other side. Impossible to tell without a visual.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1). The decorative bow could be on an elastic band that is closing the bag.

2). The bow is attached to a pin that is holding the bag closed.

3). There is a drawstring inside the bag at the close. The bow is only attached to the top layer, not sewn through.

4). The maker attached little magnets inside the bag that keep it closed.

However, it is entirely possible that the particular image you shared is not meant to be opened. It could be a bag of potpourri, meant to look pretty and go in a sock drawer, but never to be opened.

Comment: I am very much leaning towards “just decorative, never to be opened again”.